# Showing errors for mat-chip-grid with formArray

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm using mat-chip-grid to edit values of a `FormArray<FormControl<string>>`, it's great, but I can't figure out how to show errors. I'm using modified example from documentation:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Values</mat-label>
    <mat-chip-grid #chipGrid aria-label="Enter values" formArrayName="values" [errorStateMatcher]="errorStateMatcher">
        <mat-chip-row
            *ngFor="let valueControl of form.controls.values.controls; let valueIndex = index"
            (removed)="removeValue(form.controls.values, valueIndex)" [editable]="true">
            {{ valueControl.value }}
            <button matChipRemove [attr.aria-label]="'remove ' + valueControl.value">
                <mat-icon>cancel</mat-icon>
            </button>
        </mat-chip-row>
        <input class="form-control" placeholder="New value..." [matChipInputFor]="chipGrid"
            [matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes]="separatorKeysCodes" [matChipInputAddOnBlur]="true"
            (matChipInputTokenEnd)="addValue(form.controls.values, $event)" required/>
    </mat-chip-grid>
    <mat-error *ngIf="form.controls.values.invalid">At least one value is required</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

I can't make the error appear, I've tried checking for invalid on the FormArray, which is true, then tried to use a custom errorStateMatcher which is being ignored and never runs.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a Material issue to me. Removing the `*ngIf` from `mat-error` still doesn't display the error. I solved this by adding a custom `div` that displays the error underneath the form field like so:

```html
<mat-form-field>
    ...
</mat-form-field>
<div *ngIf="form.controls.values.invalid" class="error">At least one value is required</div>
```

I would also advise to add some simple styling:

```css
.error {
  color: red;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

**EDIT**

I submitted a bug report with Angular Material at https://github.com/angular/components/issues/26728